# VS Code Typescript intellisense reports errors which don't exist

Tags: typescript, intellisense, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code v1.4.0, Typescript v1.8.10.

VS Code intellisense is complaining that some of my imported modules don't exist. However, I have the required typings and have configured `tsconfig.json` as shown below.

**Example Class**

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {EventAggregator} from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';
import {UserService} from '../services/UserService';
import {OperatorService} from '../services/OperatorService';

@inject(EventAggregator, UserService, OperatorService)
export class AuthContext {
    // ...

    public initialize(): Promise<boolean> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In this class, intellisense gives me the following errors:

- Cannot find module 'aurelia-framework', 'aurelia-event-aggregator'.
- Experimental support for decorators is a feature ... set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.
- Cannot find name 'Promise'.

The "cannot find module" errors shouldn't show up because I have the typings defined (see below).

The "experimental decorators" error shouldn't show up because I've already enabled this option in `tsconfig.json`.

The "cannot find Promise" errors shouldn't show up because I've added the `es6-shim` typing.

**typings.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "dependencies": {
    "aurelia-binding": "github:aurelia/binding",
    "aurelia-bootstrapper": "github:aurelia/bootstrapper",
    "aurelia-dependency-injection": "github:aurelia/dependency-injection",
    "aurelia-dialog": "github:aurelia/dialog",
    "aurelia-event-aggregator": "github:aurelia/event-aggregator",
    "aurelia-fetch-client": "github:aurelia/fetch-client",
    "aurelia-framework": "github:aurelia/framework",
    "aurelia-history": "github:aurelia/history",
    "aurelia-history-browser": "github:aurelia/history-browser",
    "aurelia-loader": "github:aurelia/loader",
    "aurelia-logging": "github:aurelia/logging",
    "aurelia-logging-console": "github:aurelia/logging-console",
    "aurelia-metadata": "github:aurelia/metadata",
    "aurelia-pal": "github:aurelia/pal",
    "aurelia-pal-browser": "github:aurelia/pal-browser",
    "aurelia-path": "github:aurelia/path",
    "aurelia-polyfills": "github:aurelia/polyfills",
    "aurelia-route-recognizer": "github:aurelia/route-recognizer",
    "aurelia-router": "github:aurelia/router",
    "aurelia-task-queue": "github:aurelia/task-queue",
    "aurelia-templating": "github:aurelia/templating",
    "aurelia-templating-binding": "github:aurelia/templating-binding",
    "aurelia-templating-resources": "github:aurelia/templating-resources",
    "aurelia-templating-router": "github:aurelia/templating-router"
  },
  "globalDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160602141504",
    "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20160704162008",
    "materialize-css": "registry:dt/materialize-css#0.97.5+20160628040906",
    "moment-node": "registry:dt/moment-node#2.11.1+20160511043338",
    "url": "github:aurelia/fetch-client/doc/url.d.ts#bbe0777ef710d889a05759a65fa2c9c3865fc618",
    "whatwg-fetch": "registry:dt/whatwg-fetch#0.0.0+20160524142046"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "version": "1.8.10",
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"]
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts",
    "./typings/index.d.ts",
    "./typings/custom/**/*.d.ts",
    "./jspm_packages/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "jspm_packages"
  ]
}
```

Comment: isn't `filesGlob` a custom option of Atom-Typescript (i.e. not available in VS Code)? [tsconfig.json def](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to take a look at that.

Comment: I've enlisted `tsconfig-glob` to expand `filesGlob` into `files`, but I still get the same issues w/intellisense.